# set value in HiddenField with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, hidden-field

I have a problem of setting value on HiddenFiled with javascrip on ASP.NET
my HiddenFiled code is:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" Value="before" runat="server" />
```

my JS code in ASP.NET is:

```
function HandleIT(id) {

    alert(document.getElementById('<%=hidden.ClientID %>').value);

    document.getElementById('<%=hidden.ClientID %>').value = "test";

    alert(document.getElementById('<%=hidden.ClientID %>').value);

    <%Session["search"] = hidden.Value;%>

    window.location.assign("Search.aspx");
}
```

so the first alert show me "before" and the second one show me "test". so far so good. but when it goes to Search.aspx and i am using Session["search"] its showing me "before"
any idea why is it happaning?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<%Session["search"] = hidden.Value;%>
```

get the value from codebehind that is rendered before any changes by client-side.
So the value is the default value of field when is was rendered at first.

**EDIT:**

I think you can't set the session exactly in this way and in the ASPX page.
It's because lifecycle of ASP.net.
You have to do a postback to get the new value of hidden field. Postback maybe call to a full postback or partial postback or even an ajax postback.

I think that maybe it's possible using a public propery at first, but it is not.
You can check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011515/set-c-sharp-property-value-by-javascript)

As you know even when we want to pass value from javascript to codebehind, we have to use hiddenfields like [This](http://forums.asp.net/p/1211504/2139016.aspx#2139016).

Anyway i think you have to set the session's value in codebehind.

Comment: thanks you, so there is better way to make it work?

Comment: As i say you have to set the session value after a post-back (like click on a button or ...) in codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

The code that sets the session variable gets run when the page is rendered and before the JavaScript is run. This is the difference between client n server side code.

Comment: There are many tricks to do that, but your code is not complete and it's hard to provide a perfect help.
When the `HandleIT` is called? you can assign an codebehind click event to a button or hidden button in codebehind set the session.